# How to display pairwise relationship between variables in R?

Tags: r, charts, histogram

How to display pairwise relationship between variables, if "UniqueCarrier" is a character and "Delay" contains 0 and 1?

```
plot(Delay ~ UniqueCarrier, data = mydata)
```

Comment: Downvoting the question does not require any brain work, though answering this question seems to require too much brain work;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `barplot` in the following way to show counts of 1's for each unique value of the character variable

```
# Generate sample data
uniqueCarrier <- unlist(lapply(1:10, function(i) rep(paste(sample(letters,size = 3), collapse=""),10)))
Delay <- rbinom(100, 1, prob = rep(c(.30, .2, .1, .5, .7, .6, .9, .2, .7, .6),each = 10))

# Create the plot
barplot(by(data = Delay, INDICES = uniqueCarrier, sum), cex.names = 0.9)
```

[image]

**Data generated**

```
> dput(uniqueCarrier)
c("ekp", "ekp", "ekp", "ekp", "ekp", "ekp", "ekp", "ekp", "ekp", 
"ekp", "vtq", "vtq", "vtq", "vtq", "vtq", "vtq", "vtq", "vtq", 
"vtq", "vtq", "jic", "jic", "jic", "jic", "jic", "jic", "jic", 
"jic", "jic", "jic", "sab", "sab", "sab", "sab", "sab", "sab", 
"sab", "sab", "sab", "sab", "ekl", "ekl", "ekl", "ekl", "ekl", 
"ekl", "ekl", "ekl", "ekl", "ekl", "ifx", "ifx", "ifx", "ifx", 
"ifx", "ifx", "ifx", "ifx", "ifx", "ifx", "miw", "miw", "miw", 
"miw", "miw", "miw", "miw", "miw", "miw", "miw", "oif", "oif", 
"oif", "oif", "oif", "oif", "oif", "oif", "oif", "oif", "qto", 
"qto", "qto", "qto", "qto", "qto", "qto", "qto", "qto", "qto", 
"vqw", "vqw", "vqw", "vqw", "vqw", "vqw", "vqw", "vqw", "vqw", 
"vqw")
> dput(Delay)
c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)
```

Comment: If I run this: barplot(by(data = mydata$Delay, INDICES = mydata$UniqueCarrier, sum),axes = TRUE,cex.names = 0.9)
then I get this error: 'sum' not defined for ordered factors. The thing is that "Delay" is ordered factor.

Comment: You can then use `as.numeric(Delay) -1` to use its numerical representation (if factor level 1 is the actual zero's, and factor level 2 is one).